# Why can't I see the keys of an Error object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am mystified by the fact that when I create a new Error object I can see its message or name, but I can't see a list of its keys by using the standard ways.  Why is that?

```
> err = new Error("an error")
[Error: an error]
> err.message
'an error'
> err.name
'Error'
> Object.keys(err)
[]
> JSON.stringify(err)
'{}'
```

Comment: Try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` instead of `Object.keys()`. They may be non-enumerable.

Comment: As an example, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(err, 'stack')` shows `enumerable: false`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

JavaScript properties may be *non-enumerable*, which means they does not appear in `for..in` loops or `Object.keys` results.

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to get all properties (enumerable or non-enumerable) directly on an object. I say "directly" because normal enumeration looks up the object's prototype chain to get enumerable properties on parent prototypes, while `getOwnPropertyNames` does not.

Thus, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)` only shows

```
['stack',
 'arguments',
 'type',
 'message']
```

The `name` property is a non-enumerable property of `Error.prototype` and is never set directly on an `Error` instance. (Prototyping recap: when you try to access `err.name`, the lookup `err` turns up nothing, so the interpreter looks at `Error.prototype`, which does have a `name` property.)

Comment: I still can't see the `stack` property in Firefox 45: `e = new Error("Hi!"); Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e);  // Array [ "fileName", "lineNumber", "columnNumber", "message" ]`.

Comment: @kiroh I don't have Firefox to test on, but what does `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(err))` produce? It may be that in Firefox `stack` is an inherited accessor property. (Confirm this with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(err), "stack")` and checking for `get` and `set` properties.)

Comment: @apsillers Thanks! It was in fact an accessor property of the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'm using to send whole error object via http requests:

```
// Creating a custom error
const newError = new Error('This is a new error!');
newError.name = 'Error Name';

// Function that re-create error as a regular JS Object
const getErrorObject = (error) =>
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = error[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});

getErrorObject(newError);

/** Output:
{
  message: 'This is a new error!',
  name: 'Error Name',
  stack: 'Error Name: This is a new error!\n    at <anonymous>:1:20',
};
*/
```

This catch all error object value, even when receiving custom error objects.