# Object spread an Error results in no message property

Tags: javascript, custom-errors, object-destructuring

I'm trying to **spread an Error** so that I can alter the error without affecting the original error.

```js
const error = new Error('Error test');

const freeError = {...error};
console.log(error, freeError);
```

But the output is an empty object `{}`. I'm expecting the `freeError` have at least **a message property, but there is none**.

Is this a part of JavaScript feature or is there something wrong with my code or engine?

I know a way to fix this, but it requires an extra work `{...error, message: error.message}`. So, yeah, all I need is a **clarification** so that I can be sure that I am not missing something. Thank you.

Comment: As you can see `error` also logs as `{}`.

Comment: @connexo, error has the message property but freeError does not have

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277890/why-cant-i-see-the-keys-of-an-error-object

Comment: @Tick20 That is explicitly addressed in my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Object spread [only copies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) enumerable own properties, and at least in some environments, the `message` is not an enumerable own property.

In Chrome, it's a non-enumerable own property, and in Firefox, it's a property of `Error.prototype`:

```js
const error = new Error('Error test');

// Chrome logs an object (including "enumerable": false,)
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(error, 'message'));

// Firefox logs an object (including "enumerable": false,)
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(error), 'message'));
```

It's implementation-dependent. I'd manually extract all properties you need:

```js
const error = new Error('Error test');
const { message, stack } = error;
const freeError = { message, stack };
console.log(freeError);
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, please note that what you are doing is not *destructuring* - it is called *object spread*.

Spreading objects only takes `ownProperty`s into account. `Error` instances don't have any non-inherited properties. That is why `console.log(error)` also outputs `{}`:

```js
const error = new Error('Error test');

const freeError = {...error};
console.log(error, freeError);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Properties

Because inherited properties are not part of the spread result object, `error` does have a message property (inherited from its prototype), whereas `freeError` does not have it.

Check this example:

```js
const str = new String('Hello world');

const freeStr = { ...str };

console.log(str.length); // 11
console.log(freeStr.length); // undefined
```

As you can see `str` **does have** a `length` property (inherited from the `String` `prototype`), whereas `freeStr` **does not have** it (for the same reason as in your example).

[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_instances]

Again, see MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Error_instances

Answer (score 1):

```
const freeError = {...error};
```

is similar to

```
const freeError = Object.assign({}, error);
```

If you want to get the properties,

```
const freeError = Object.assign({message: error.message}, error);
```