# Weird behavior of es6 object spread

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have got the following example

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sendDevError(err, req, res);
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log(err); // { message: 'test message', statusCode: '404', status: 'failed' }
    let error = { ...err };
    console.log(error); // { statusCode: '404', status: 'failed' }
    // error.message = err.message;
    if (error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);
    if (error.code === 11000) error = handleDuplicateFieldsDB(error);
    if (error.name === 'ValidationError')
      error = handleValidationErrorDB(error);
    if (error.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') error = handleJWTError();
    if (error.name === 'TokenExpiredError') error = handleJWTExpiredError();
    sendProdError(error, req, res);
  }
};
```

The magic comes along with object spread. When im cloning `err` object that for some reason `message` property is missing in my clone object. I solved this by just putting `error.message = err.message` after object spread. But this approach is not what im trying to achieve. Could someone explain me how object spread is working under the hood? And what could i do to play around this weird bug?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59874163/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Wow, I wish I'd see that link earlier. It never occurred to me this *exact* question had come up before. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking why `message` isn't copied when you do this:

```
let error = { ...err };
```

The answer is that property spread only processes *own*, *enumerable* properties of the source object. The [`message` property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-error.prototype.message) of `Error` instances is an inherited property, not an "own" property.

Here's an example showing that distinction in action:

```js
const p = {message: "value"};
const c = Object.create(p);
c.own = "prop";
console.log(c.message);                   // "value";
console.log("message" in c);              // true
console.log(c.hasOwnProperty("message")); // false

console.log({...c}); // {"own": "prop"}

// Copy message onto the object
c.message = c.message;
console.log({...c}); // {"own": "prop", "message": "value"}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```